# Create user in Firebase, Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a user in Firebase, but nothing happens when I am using the createUser() function.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://myApp-88ea7.firebaseio.com/");
                ref.createUser(email, password, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
                        Log.i("SUCCESS", "Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid"));
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                        // there was an error
                        Log.i("Error", firebaseError.getDetails());
                    }
                });
```

In fact, I don't seem to enter either onSuccess() or onError(). I am trying to follow [this guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/password.html)

I have enabled sign-in methods. I get this message when calling the function:

> call createSocket() return a new socket

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your url correct?

Comment: Quote firebase.com "You're viewing the legacy docs. They are deprecated as of May 18, 2016.These docs are for version 2.5.2 and below of the Java SDK. Go to our current docs, or see our Android migration guide."

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I was just following the out-of-date guide, [this is the right one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account)